# How to convert text table to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing

I am trying to scrape the "PRINCIPAL STOCKHOLDERS" table from the link[text file](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1034239/0000950124-97-003372.txt)and convert it to a csv file. Right now I am only half successful. Namely, I can locate the table and parse it but somehow I cannot convert the text table to a standard one. My code is attached. Can someone help me with it?

```
url = r'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1034239/0000950124-97-003372.txt'

# Different approach, the first approach does not work
filing_url = requests.get(url)
content = filing_url.text
splited_data = content.split('\n')


table_title = 'PRINCIPAL STOCKHOLDERS'
END_TABLE_LINE = '- ------------------------'

def find_no_line_start_table(table_title,splited_data):
    found_no_lines = []
    for index, line in enumerate(splited_data):
        if table_title in line:
            found_no_lines.append(index)

    return found_no_lines

table_start = find_no_line_start_table(table_title,splited_data)

# I need help with locating the table. If I locate the table use the above function, it will return two locations and I have to manually choose the correct one. 
 
table_start = table_start[1]

def get_start_data_table(table_start, splited_data):
    for index, row in enumerate(splited_data[table_start:]):
        if '<C>' in row:
            return table_start + index

def get_end_table(start_table_data, splited_data ):
    for index, row in enumerate(splited_data[start_table_data:]):
            if END_TABLE_LINE in row:
                return start_table_data + index

def row(l):
    l = l.split()
    number_columns = 8
    if len(l) >= number_columns:
        data_row = [''] * number_columns
        first_column_done = False

        index = 0
        for w in l:
            if not first_column_done:
                data_row[0] = ' '.join([data_row[0], w])
                if ':' in w:
                        first_column_done = True
            else:
                index += 1
                data_row[index] = w

        return data_row

start_line = get_start_data_table(table_start, splited_data)
end_line = get_end_table(start_line, splited_data)

table = splited_data[start_line : end_line]

# I also need help with convert the text table to a CSV file, somehow the following function does not #recognize my column.
 
def take_table(table):
    owner = []
    Num_share = []
    middle = []
    middle_1 = []
    middle_2 = []
    middle_3 = []
    prior_offering = []
    after_offering = []

    for r in table:
        data_row = row(r)
        if data_row:
            col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5, col_6, col_7, col_8 = data_row
            owner.append(col_1)
            Num_share.append(col_2)
            middle.append(col_3)
            middle_1.append(col_4)
            middle_2.append(col_5)
            middle_3.append(col_6)
            prior_offering.append(col_7)
            after_offering.append(col_8)

    table_data = {'owner': owner, 'Num_share': Num_share, 'middle': middle, 'middle_1': middle_1,
                  'middle_2': middle_2, 'middle_3': middle_3, 'prior_offering': prior_offering,
                  'after_offering': after_offering}
    return table_data

#print (table)
dict_table = take_table(table)
a = pd.DataFrame(dict_table)
a.to_csv('trail.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_table)
```

instead of

```
pd.DataFrame(dict_table)
```